# the stuffs i edit disappear in blender

Tags: modeling

i download a model online, and when i try to edit, i can see the edit that i made but when i change to object view, all of the edit disappear and i have to make another vertices so i can see the edit again (it's not hidden)
[image]
[image]

as you can see, part of the hair, and the skirt

Comment: Are there any mask modifiers?

Comment: how can i know?

Comment: Looks like you added an edge without a face, that won't show up in object mode. 
Other than that, sounds like shape keys.You find them under the green triangle, Object Data Properties

Comment: thanks, it was the key